# fwrite result PHP

Tags: php, fwrite

Im currently trying to write a few words on a file, and then open it.

currently, i do have the following outcome:

[image]

When my desired outcome would be something like:

[image]

How come it is like that?

TextAr is just some numbers from a textarea. ( one id each line)
code:

```
 $text = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", trim($_POST['ids']));

$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
    foreach ($textAr as $k=>$v) if(empty(trim($v))) unset($textAr[$k]);



$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

  $handle = fopen("file.txt", "w");
$saveresult = '';

foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    $line = str_replace(' ', '', $line);
    $line = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $line);
    $result = httpPost($url, $line);
    $showID = ($showID ? "".$result['id']." -" : '');
    $notexisting = ($showasnull ? 0 : "N/A");

    if ($result['manual'] == true) {
        $saveresult .= "".$showID." Manual".PHP_EOL;

    }
    if ($result['hit'] == true && $result['manual'] != true) {
        $saveresult .= "".$showID." " . $result['price'] . "".PHP_EOL;


    } else if ($result['hit'] == false) {
        $saveresult .= "".$showID." ".$notexisting."".PHP_EOL;

    }

    $saveresult .= "\r\n";

    ?>


<?PHP }
fwrite($handle, $saveresult);
fclose($handle);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('file.txt'));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
readfile('file.txt');
```

*EDIT*

i removed         `$saveresult .= "\r\n";` but still same result.

***EDIT 2:***

example of textAr:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "43631132" [1]=> string(8) "43631132" }
```

example of `$result`

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(8) "43631132" ["price"]=> int(0) ["hit"]=> bool(false) ["manual"]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: Can you please describe array of $textAr ??

Comment: sure, but why is that nessesary while im only writing lines? :) @Darshanambaliya

Comment: Can you check if it is a \r\n delimiter instead of \n?

Comment: i want to debug from top thats why @maria

Comment: @KaranPunamiya how do i do that?

Comment: Use \r\n to split between lines. Replace multiple occurances of \r\n with single \r\n

Comment: `$text = preg_replace('/(\r\n+)/', "\r\n", trim($_POST['ids']));`

`$textAr = explode("\r\n", $text);`

Comment: @KaranPunamiya i acually removed the new line saveresult, still excactly same result.

Comment: have you tried a `if(!empty($line)){` right after the `foreach($line loop` ?

Comment: Hello @KaranPunamiya i think before delimiter it will prints N/A so i think we have to first debug the array what you think ? mariya can you please post the array

Comment: @Darshanambaliya edited the post to reflect array and result.

Comment: You know you can write to a file progressively, you don't need to store everything in a single string and write at the end.

Comment: any suggestions then @apokryfos ? anway, dont know why it writes like that :|

Answer (score 0):

You can write each line independantly. This way you can check if the line itself is empty before writing.

```
foreach ($textAr as $line) {
    $saveresult = "";
    $line = str_replace(' ', '', $line); 
    $line = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $line);
    $result = httpPost($url, $line);
    $showID = ($showID ? "".$result['id']." -" : '');
    $notexisting = ($showasnull ? 0 : "N/A");

    if ($result['manual'] == true) {
        $saveresult .= "".$showID." Manual";    
    }
    if ($result['hit'] == true && $result['manual'] != true) {
        $saveresult .= "".$showID." " . $result['price'];
    } else if ($result['hit'] == false) {
        $saveresult .= "".$showID." ".$notexisting;    
    }
    $saveresult = trim($saveresult);
    if (!empty($saveresult)) {
        fwrite($handle, $saveresult.PHP_EOL);
    }

}    
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: still wont get rid of the first lines within the file :|

Comment: @maria Can you try doing `fwrite($handle, print_r($result,1).PHP_EOL)` so you can get the actual result contents written? Could use this to debug.